# sed, replace multiple occurrences with different values

Tags: html, awk, sed

I have an HOCR file (it's basically an HTML), and i have these `.ocr_page` elements

```
  <div class="ocr_page" title="bbox 0 0 3360 4688">
  <div class="ocr_page" title="bbox 0 0 3360 4688">
  <div class="ocr_page" title="bbox 0 0 3360 4688">
  <div class="ocr_page" title="bbox 0 0 3360 4688">
  <div class="ocr_page" title="bbox 0 0 3360 4688">
  <div class="ocr_page" title="bbox 0 0 3360 4688">
```

For every of these elements i need to add a unique ID, taken from file names from a directory. So given these files:

```
img_0000.jpeg
img_0001.jpeg
img_0002.jpeg
img_0003.jpeg
img_0004.jpeg
img_0005.jpeg
```

i want

```
  <div id="img_0000.jpeg" class="ocr_page" title="bbox 0 0 3360 4688">
  <div id="img_0001.jpeg" class="ocr_page" title="bbox 0 0 3360 4688">
  <div id="img_0002.jpeg" class="ocr_page" title="bbox 0 0 3360 4688">
  <div id="img_0003.jpeg" class="ocr_page" title="bbox 0 0 3360 4688">
  <div id="img_0004.jpeg" class="ocr_page" title="bbox 0 0 3360 4688">
  <div id="img_0005.jpeg" class="ocr_page" title="bbox 0 0 3360 4688">
```

do i need an html parser (in some language) to do this? can i do with sed/awk script?

Comment: Some queries: How do I know which file name to use for a particular line? Do you mean that First div gets first file in directory ordered by name? What if there is mismatch in the number of `ocr_page` divs and number of image files? Do all `ocr_page` divs have the same content?

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -i 's/<div class="ocr_page"/<div id="img_000@#.jpeg" class="ocr_page"/g' file && a=-1 && while read in; do a=`expr "$a" + 1`; sed -i ""$in"s/@#/"$a"/" file; done <<< "$(cat file | grep 'img_.*jpeg' -n | cut -f1 -d ':')"
```

It will give following output:

```
<div id="img_0000.jpeg" class="ocr_page" title="bbox 0 0 3360 4688">
<div id="img_0001.jpeg" class="ocr_page" title="bbox 0 0 3360 4688">
<div id="img_0002.jpeg" class="ocr_page" title="bbox 0 0 3360 4688">
<div id="img_0003.jpeg" class="ocr_page" title="bbox 0 0 3360 4688">                                                          <div id="img_0004.jpeg" class="ocr_page" title="bbox 0 0 3360 4688">
<div id="img_0005.jpeg" class="ocr_page" title="bbox 0 0 3360 4688">
```

Answer (score 0):

i solved this way:

```
for file in data/*.jpeg; do
    gsed -i -e "0,/<div class=\"ocr_page\"/{s/<div class=\"ocr_page\"/<div id=\"$(basename $file)\" class=\"ocr_page\"/}" myfile.hocr
done
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 'R file2' file1 | sed -E 'N;s/<div(.*)\n(.*)/<div id="\2"\1/'
```

For each line in `file1` append a line from `file2`.

Pipe the result to a second sed invocation which combines pairs of lines into one and uses grouping and back references to manipulate the input into the final result.